# Azure Durable functions Instance Ids not found

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I've got an azure durable function in which an orchestrator gets randomly "stuck". While trying to understand what is happening, I started to investigate based on the instance id, and now there is my question: Why some instance ids from the azure portal are missing from the azure storage (5 out of 12)? I know that in theory, the portal has a delay in displaying the statuses, but some instances are not to be found, it's pretty strange.

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you provide more details like screenshots of number of instances showing and number of executions happened, what hosting plan you used to deploy your Azure Durable functions?\

Comment: I am using elastic premium hosting plan, limited at 1 instance. Just upgraded from consumption plan. Before the upgrade I don't recall having this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long hours of talking and debugging with Microsoft support, it seems there was a bug in the durable functions SDK. Now the issue was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Azure Functions Premium hosting plan (.NET 6) set the `Maximum Burst` value to `20` in Scale Out Window.

I have published a basic .NET 6 durable function to 2 Azure premium Function Apps where one having `Maximum Burst` is `20` and `1` for another Premium Function App.

**I found that the Instance Ids are lesser in Orchestration Traces than the Invocation traces**:

[image: FuncAppMaxBurst20]

> Why some instance ids from the azure portal are missing from the azure storage (5 out of 12)?

The major difference between the Invocation Traces and Orchestration traces is:

For each activity status like Started, Scheduled, Awaited, Completed - the instance ID will be logged in **Invocation Traces** whereas in the **Orchestration Traces**, you will find the less instance IDs in which each Instance Id has complete information of that function activity/execution status.

[image]

Comment: Totally agree, but still doesn't make any sense why they do not exist in the azure storage, or why they were deleted